# How to import a file or external database into SQLite android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

I am trying to create an android application for searching contacts using sqlite database. How to import contacts of around 2000(in a file, excel or json or xml) or else external database into my database when the app is installed for the first time. I got this code from online, I made some changes according to my requirement.

Main activity

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import com.example.myapplication.adapter.ContactListAdapter;
import com.example.myapplication.database.DatabaseHelper;
import com.example.myapplication.entities.Contact;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.view.Menu;

import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listViewContact;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initView();
        //loadData();
    }

    private void initView() {
        listViewContact = findViewById(R.id.listViewContact);
        registerForContextMenu(listViewContact);
    }

    private void loadData() {
        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        List<Contact> contacts = databaseHelper.findAll();
        if (contacts != null) {
            listViewContact.setAdapter(new ContactListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), contacts));
        }
    }

    @Override

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.searchView).getActionView();
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                searchContact(query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                searchContact(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private void searchContact(String keyword) {
        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        List<Contact> contacts = databaseHelper.search(keyword);
        if (contacts != null) {
            listViewContact.setAdapter(new ContactListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), contacts));
        }


    }

    }
```

Database helper (This is my DBhelper class)

```
package com.example.myapplication.database;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import com.example.myapplication.entities.Contact;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String dbName = "ts_telephone";
    private static int dbVersion = 1;

    private static String telephone = "telephone";

    private static String idColumn = "Id";
    private static String PrefixColumn = "Prefix";
    private static String nameColumn = "name";
    private static String designationColumn = "designation";
    private static String departmentColumn = "department";
    private static String sectionColumn = "section";
    private static String addressColumn = "designation";
    private static String std_codeColumn = "std_code";
    private static String od_vpnColumn = "od_vpn";
    private static String odColumn = "od";
    private static String r_phoneColumn = "r_phone";
    private static String r_vpnColumn = "r_vpn";
    private static String cell_noColumn = "cell_no";
    private static String faxColumn = "fax";
    private static String emailColumn = "email";
    private static String IntercomColumn = "Intercom";
    //sl_no     prefix  name    designation department  section address std_code    od_vpn  od  r_phone r_vpn   cell_no fax email   Intercom


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, dbName, null, dbVersion);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase ts_telephone) {

        ts_telephone.execSQL("create table " + telephone + "(" +
                idColumn + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                PrefixColumn + " text, " +
                nameColumn + " text, " +
                designationColumn + " text, " +
                departmentColumn + " text, " +
                sectionColumn + " text, " +
                addressColumn + " text, " +
                std_codeColumn + " text, " +
                od_vpnColumn + " text, " +
                odColumn +"text,"+
                r_phoneColumn + " text, " +
                r_vpnColumn + " text, " +
                cell_noColumn + " text," +
                faxColumn + " text, " +
                emailColumn + " text," +
                IntercomColumn + " text " +

                ")"
        );

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("drop table if exists " + telephone);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }


    public List<Contact> findAll() {
        List<Contact> contacts = null;
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from " + telephone, null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
                do {
                    Contact contact = new Contact();
                    contact.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
                    contact.setPrefix(cursor.getString(1));
                    contact.setName(cursor.getString(2));
                    contact.setDesignation(cursor.getString(3));
                    contact.setDepartment(cursor.getString(4));
                    contact.setSection(cursor.getString(5));
                    contact.setAddress(cursor.getString(6));
                    contact.setStd_code(cursor.getString(7));
                    contact.setOd_vpn(cursor.getString(8));
                    contact.setOd(cursor.getString(9));
                    contact.setR_phone(cursor.getString(10));
                    contact.setR_vpn(cursor.getString(11));
                    contact.setCell_no(cursor.getString(12));
                    contact.setFax(cursor.getString(13));
                    contact.setEmail(cursor.getString(14));
                    contact.setIntercom(cursor.getString(15));
                    contacts.add(contact);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            contacts = null;
        }
        return contacts;
    }

    public List<Contact> search(String keyword) {
        List<Contact> contacts = null;
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from " + telephone + " where " + nameColumn + " like ?"  , new String[]{"%" + keyword + "%"});
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
                do {
                    Contact contact = new Contact();
                    contact.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
                    contact.setPrefix(cursor.getString(1));
                    contact.setName(cursor.getString(2));
                    contact.setDesignation(cursor.getString(3));
                    contact.setDepartment(cursor.getString(4));
                    contact.setSection(cursor.getString(5));
                    contact.setAddress(cursor.getString(6));
                    contact.setStd_code(cursor.getString(7));
                    contact.setOd_vpn(cursor.getString(8));
                    contact.setOd(cursor.getString(9));
                    contact.setR_phone(cursor.getString(10));
                    contact.setR_vpn(cursor.getString(11));
                    contact.setCell_no(cursor.getString(12));
                    contact.setFax(cursor.getString(13));
                    contact.setEmail(cursor.getString(14));
                    contact.setIntercom(cursor.getString(15));
                    contacts.add(contact);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            contacts = null;
        }
        return contacts;


    }



    public boolean create(Contact contact) {
        boolean result = true;
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(PrefixColumn, contact.getPrefix());
            contentValues.put(nameColumn, contact.getName());
            contentValues.put(designationColumn, contact.getDesignation());
            contentValues.put(departmentColumn, contact.getDepartment());
            contentValues.put(sectionColumn, contact.getSection());
            contentValues.put(addressColumn, contact.getAddress());
            contentValues.put(std_codeColumn, contact.getStd_code());
            contentValues.put(od_vpnColumn, contact.getOd_vpn());
            contentValues.put(odColumn, contact.getOd());
            contentValues.put(r_phoneColumn, contact.getR_phone());
            contentValues.put(r_vpnColumn, contact.getR_vpn());
            contentValues.put(cell_noColumn, contact.getCell_no());
            contentValues.put(faxColumn, contact.getFax());
            contentValues.put(emailColumn, contact.getEmail());
            contentValues.put(IntercomColumn, contact.getIntercom());
            result = sqLiteDatabase.insert(telephone, null, contentValues) > 0;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;

    }
}
```

contact.java

```
package com.example.myapplication.database;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import com.example.myapplication.entities.Contact;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String dbName = "ts_telephone";
    private static int dbVersion = 1;

    private static String telephone = "telephone";

    private static String idColumn = "Id";
    private static String PrefixColumn = "Prefix";
    private static String nameColumn = "name";
    private static String designationColumn = "designation";
    private static String departmentColumn = "department";
    private static String sectionColumn = "section";
    private static String addressColumn = "designation";
    private static String std_codeColumn = "std_code";
    private static String od_vpnColumn = "od_vpn";
    private static String odColumn = "od";
    private static String r_phoneColumn = "r_phone";
    private static String r_vpnColumn = "r_vpn";
    private static String cell_noColumn = "cell_no";
    private static String faxColumn = "fax";
    private static String emailColumn = "email";
    private static String IntercomColumn = "Intercom";
    //sl_no     prefix  name    designation department  section address std_code    od_vpn  od  r_phone r_vpn   cell_no fax email   Intercom


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, dbName, null, dbVersion);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase ts_telephone) {

        ts_telephone.execSQL("create table " + telephone + "(" +
                idColumn + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                PrefixColumn + " text, " +
                nameColumn + " text, " +
                designationColumn + " text, " +
                departmentColumn + " text, " +
                sectionColumn + " text, " +
                addressColumn + " text, " +
                std_codeColumn + " text, " +
                od_vpnColumn + " text, " +
                odColumn +"text,"+
                r_phoneColumn + " text, " +
                r_vpnColumn + " text, " +
                cell_noColumn + " text," +
                faxColumn + " text, " +
                emailColumn + " text," +
                IntercomColumn + " text " +

                ")"
        );

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("drop table if exists " + telephone);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }


    public List<Contact> findAll() {
        List<Contact> contacts = null;
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from " + telephone, null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
                do {
                    Contact contact = new Contact();
                    contact.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
                    contact.setPrefix(cursor.getString(1));
                    contact.setName(cursor.getString(2));
                    contact.setDesignation(cursor.getString(3));
                    contact.setDepartment(cursor.getString(4));
                    contact.setSection(cursor.getString(5));
                    contact.setAddress(cursor.getString(6));
                    contact.setStd_code(cursor.getString(7));
                    contact.setOd_vpn(cursor.getString(8));
                    contact.setOd(cursor.getString(9));
                    contact.setR_phone(cursor.getString(10));
                    contact.setR_vpn(cursor.getString(11));
                    contact.setCell_no(cursor.getString(12));
                    contact.setFax(cursor.getString(13));
                    contact.setEmail(cursor.getString(14));
                    contact.setIntercom(cursor.getString(15));
                    contacts.add(contact);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            contacts = null;
        }
        return contacts;
    }

    public List<Contact> search(String keyword) {
        List<Contact> contacts = null;
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from " + telephone + " where " + nameColumn + " like ?"  , new String[]{"%" + keyword + "%"});
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
                do {
                    Contact contact = new Contact();
                    contact.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
                    contact.setPrefix(cursor.getString(1));
                    contact.setName(cursor.getString(2));
                    contact.setDesignation(cursor.getString(3));
                    contact.setDepartment(cursor.getString(4));
                    contact.setSection(cursor.getString(5));
                    contact.setAddress(cursor.getString(6));
                    contact.setStd_code(cursor.getString(7));
                    contact.setOd_vpn(cursor.getString(8));
                    contact.setOd(cursor.getString(9));
                    contact.setR_phone(cursor.getString(10));
                    contact.setR_vpn(cursor.getString(11));
                    contact.setCell_no(cursor.getString(12));
                    contact.setFax(cursor.getString(13));
                    contact.setEmail(cursor.getString(14));
                    contact.setIntercom(cursor.getString(15));
                    contacts.add(contact);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            contacts = null;
        }
        return contacts;


    }



    public boolean create(Contact contact) {
        boolean result = true;
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(PrefixColumn, contact.getPrefix());
            contentValues.put(nameColumn, contact.getName());
            contentValues.put(designationColumn, contact.getDesignation());
            contentValues.put(departmentColumn, contact.getDepartment());
            contentValues.put(sectionColumn, contact.getSection());
            contentValues.put(addressColumn, contact.getAddress());
            contentValues.put(std_codeColumn, contact.getStd_code());
            contentValues.put(od_vpnColumn, contact.getOd_vpn());
            contentValues.put(odColumn, contact.getOd());
            contentValues.put(r_phoneColumn, contact.getR_phone());
            contentValues.put(r_vpnColumn, contact.getR_vpn());
            contentValues.put(cell_noColumn, contact.getCell_no());
            contentValues.put(faxColumn, contact.getFax());
            contentValues.put(emailColumn, contact.getEmail());
            contentValues.put(IntercomColumn, contact.getIntercom());
            result = sqLiteDatabase.insert(telephone, null, contentValues) > 0;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;

    }
}
```

Comment: There is no problem description. If you can put data in a database and can read data from a file then what are you asking for? Please start explaining the problem.

Comment: How to do one time insertion through a file ?

Comment: I do not understand what you want. Please clarify your problem.